# shift first 100 bytes of a file to the end of the file and save then back again and save again

Tags: c#, arrays, filestream

I need to move the first 100 bytes of a file to the end of the file, then save that file (windows forms app).  I then need the reverse process (to move the 100 bytes at the end back to the beginning then save again).

Some of these files are VERY large (over 2GB) so I can't use file.readallbytes because I get out of memory exceptions.

I've tried playing around with a filestream and using filestream.position, but I can't wrap my head around moving the bytes then saving the file.

any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It will involve physical moving the bytes. So you just read 101th byte and write it to the 1st. Then 102th to 2nd, ... Then you append the first 100 bytes that you initially stored in some array to the end and get a winners beer.

Comment: I'm ok just making the first 100 bytes 0's if that makes it easier, then adding them to the end of the file. Then when the reverse happens, replacing those 0 bytes with the real values from the end and deleting the 100 off the tail...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to use a byte buffer so you are only processing a small portion of the file at a time. It sounds like you have the right approach, but there are a few gotchas along the way.

Here's an example showing how I'd approach it:

```
public enum SwapType
{
    FrontToBack,
    BackToFront
}

public static class EndSwap
{
    public static void DoSwap(string path, SwapType swapType)
    {
        if (path == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("path", 
                "You must supply a path to the file.");
        }
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.");
        }

        string tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        byte[] swapBytes = new byte[100];

        using (FileStream inputFs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, 
            FileAccess.Read))
        using (FileStream outputFs = new FileStream(tempPath, 
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            int bytesRead = -1;

            if (swapType == SwapType.FrontToBack)
            {
                // We want to keep hold of the first 100 bytes of the file
                // and output them after copying the rest of file
                inputFs.Read(swapBytes, 0, 100);
            }
            else
            {
                // Read the last 100 bytes of the file
                inputFs.Seek(-100, SeekOrigin.End);
                inputFs.Read(swapBytes, 0, 100);
                // Output them straight to the output file
                outputFs.Write(swapBytes, 0, 100);
                // Reposition to the beginning of the input file
                inputFs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            }

            // The number of bytes left to copy is 100 less than the file 
            // length
            long bytesRemaining = inputFs.Length - 100;

            // Copy the rest of the bytes
            while (bytesRemaining > 0)
            {
                bytesRead = inputFs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                // NB: the number of bytes read could be more than the 
                // number remaining
                outputFs.Write(buffer, 0,
                    (int)Math.Min(bytesRead, bytesRemaining));
                bytesRemaining -= bytesRead;
            }

            // Don't forget to append the start bytes if required
            if (swapType == SwapType.FrontToBack)
            {
                outputFs.Write(swapBytes, 0, 100);
            }
        }

        // Now swap the files themselves
        File.Delete(path);
        File.Move(tempPath, path);
        // NB: could do File.Replace() if backup is needed
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
// Copy first 100 bytes to end
EndSwap.DoSwap(@"C:\Users\Dave\Downloads\MyTest.pdf", SwapType.FrontToBack);
// Copy those same 100 bytes back to the beginning again
EndSwap.DoSwap(@"C:\Users\Dave\Downloads\MyTest.pdf", SwapType.BackToFront);
```

The end result is identical to the original file, of course.

Comment: this is perfect.  I wish I could mark both of these answers as correct, but since you provided the full way of how to get it back, this one is better cause I was stuck trying to figure out the return path on the other answer.  Thanks.  Still +1 for both of you :)

Answer (score 4):

You should not read all data into memory. By using FileStream you can read multiple chunks of data, e.g. 1 KB each, and storing it in a new File. Start at position 100, to skip the first bytes. After rearranging the complete file, add the skipped bytes at the end. Finally move the new file on the position of the old file. By raising maxBufferSize you can fasten up the copy process, but using more memory.

To revert the changes, start with the last 100 bytes and move on from beginning until `inputStream.Length - 100`.

```
string inputFile = "C:\\input.txt";
string tempFile = "C:\\input.txt";
int dataLength = 100;
int maxBufferSize = 1024;

using (var inputStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
    int length = (int)inputStream.Length;
    int currentInputPosition = dataLength;

    inputStream.Position = currentInputPosition;

    using (var outputStream = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
        var bufferSize = Math.Min(maxBufferSize, length - currentInputPosition);

        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        while (inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize) > 0) {
            currentInputPosition += bufferSize;

            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        buffer = new byte[dataLength];
        inputStream.Position = 0;
        inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}

File.Delete(inputFile);
File.Move(tempFile, inputFile);
```

Comment: This is great thanks.  I'm a little confused on the conversion back though.  I'm starting with the last 100 like so: int currentInputPosition = length - 100; and doing my while loop to write those first 100 bytes to the new file.  I'm then setting my currentInputPosition = 0; to start at the beginning, but I'm not sure where to put the boundary for the loop to stop?